# How to Avoid Throwing An Error When SQL Select Returns Nothing

Tags: c#, mysql, null, catch-block

I read somewhere that one should never use error conditions as normal program flow. Makes excellent sense to me... But

C# application sitting on top of a MySQL db. I need to parse a string value into two parts, an ID, and a value. (The original data come from a Devonian database), then validate the value against a lookup table. So, a couple of original strings might look like this:

"6776 Purple People Eater"

"BIK  Yellow Polka-Dot Bikini (currently in use)"

"DCP  Deuce Coup"

So, my little utility parses each string into the ID and the description based on the index of the first space (fortunately, consistent). I then pass the ID to the lookup, get the new value and away we go.

Unfortunately, TPTB also decided that we no longer need no stinkin' Yellow Polka-Dot Bikinis (currently in use). So, BIK does not return a row. Here's a code snippet:

```
    foreach (string product in productTokens) {
      tempProduct = product.Trim();
      if (tempProduct.Length > 0) {
        if (tempProduct.Length < 10) {
          product_id = tempProduct;
        }
        else {
          int charPosition = tempProduct.IndexOf(" ");
          product_id = tempProduct.Substring(0, charPosition);
        }
        try {
          s_product = productAdapter.GetProductName(product_id).ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
          if (e.Message.ToString() == "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.") {
            s_product = "";
          }
          else {
            errLog.WriteLine("Invalid product ID " + e.Message.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid product ID " + e.Message.ToString());
            throw;
          } //else
        } //catch
        if (s_product.Length > 0) {
          sTemp = sTemp + s_product + "; ";
        }
      } //if product.length > 0
    } //foreach product in productTokens
```

Really, really ugly! Particularly the part where I test for an invalid IDin the catch block. There simply must be a better way to handle this.

If anyone can help me out, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling ToString() at that point, first you should check if the value returned is null;

```
object productName = productAdapter.GetProductName(product_id);
if ( productName != null )
{
    s_product = productName.ToString();
}
else
{
    s_product = String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Hmm... It didn't occur to me that the ToString() might be throwing the exception rather than the fetch. I'll give that a shot.
Thanks.

Comment: You were right! It was the .ToString() throwing the exception. If I leave that off, the request returns an object and I can test that and convert to string if not null.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the recommendations of Rob and Marc, and based on your code above, I'd suggest another tweak; I'd be really surprised if `productAdapter.GetProductName()` doesn't *already* return a `String`, in which case calling ToString() on it is utterly redundant. If it does indeed already return a `String`, then your whole try/catch block becomes one line:

```
s_product = productAdapter.GetProductName(product_id) ?? string.Empty;
```

Also, I think it might be useful to mention something else that *already* returns a `String` - `Exception.Message`. So all of the different places where you're calling ToString() in your code are also utterly redundant.

Also, I would suggest using the instance method `String.Split()` rather than the combination of `IndexOf` and `SubString`:

```
product_id = tempProduct.Split(" ", 2)[1];
```

Finally, deciding what kind of `Exception` you've caught by examining the `Message` property should be a totally last-ditch scenario. Even if you really did *need* to catch `NullReferenceException` here, you should do so *explicitly*:

```
catch (NullReferenceException) {
    s_product = "";
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // Log your invalid ID error condition here
}
```

*P.S.: I'm also not really sure what at all this question has to do with MySQL, since there's no evidence of any DB API in your code.*

Comment: Good thoughts! Thanks. 
I think productAdapter.GetProductName returns a data row with one column rather than a string, but I'll check. 
Thanks again.

Comment: I doubt it, I'm fairly sure that DataRow.ToString() always returns "System.Data.DataRow".

Comment: Yep, the GetProductName returns a datarow. But, your other points were well taken. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply check whether GetProductName returns null?

```
var productName = s_product = productAdapter.GetProductName(product_id);
if(productName == null) { ... do something }
else {
    string name = productName.ToString();
}
```